# E-commerce tracking in wordpress using woo commerce

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, ecommerce, woocommerce

I work on a small business and they asked me to "set up e-commerce tracking on Google Analytics".

First things first, some information on the webstie:

- It's on Wordpress
- I have already successfully set up the Google Analytics using Google Analytics Tag Manager
- E-commerce settings in Google Analytics are enabled
- I can see that the guy that has set up the site, has built everything using Woo Commerce, so it is set up that way and nobody wants to change that (since custom code is implemented too, for special business needs.

What I want is to make Google Analytics track and show stuff like 
what products were added to the cart

- if an item was removed
- what happened on checkout
- if payment was done what method was chosen
- if possible, have the capability to show that checking per customer
  indepedently
- any extra features are welcome

Why is this confusing to me then?

I read an article that had this link included:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

The article was suggesting me to upgrade to universal analytics and stuff, showing some manual code examples in js and php if I recall right, and overall, thank you very much for the confusion, dear article author.

Is there a way to make Google Analytics show stuff from the cart and checkout process?

Will this do the trick?
https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-google-analytics/

Will I need the pro version?
Does the plugin take care of code mentioned on that article?
Do I actually need to implement universal analytics or am I just confused?

See that was a load of information thrown on me, and that's how I feel. Lost and confused. I just want to monitor the shopping process of the customers and collect e-commerce data on google analytics.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going in the right direction you can use https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-google-analytics/ for the basic tracking while if you need some pro functionality, then you can also go ahead with Pro as Woocommerce offer 30 days money back guarantee you can try Pro plugin as well.

If you don't want to use the Pro version then you can try **[DuracellTomi's Google Tag Manager for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/)** it'll do the job whatever you're looking for.

You can also have a look on for the complete process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8ErwPDQcTo Posted By Julian Juenemann the founder and Chief Instructor of Measureschool.com

As Duracell plugin provide lots of data layer function you can use that for in-detail tracking for WooCommerce

Comment: Thank you for your time Group Of Oceninfo, I am away from my job now. On Monday I am gonna try things out again and revisit my questions again. Wishing all a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for Enhanced E-commerce tracking, search for [Tatvic's EE plugin on the WordPress plugins site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-e-commerce-for-woocommerce-store/). It works well with both the Tom Duracell plugin as well as a standalone Google Analytics plugin. I work with this plugin all the time due to the ease with which it just works.

Comment: Thank you for your time Prasad, I am away from my job now. On Monday I am gonna try things out again and revisit my questions again. Wishing all a nice weekend.